# Spring @Value FileNotFound when running on azure pipeline

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-devops, spring-annotations

In my spring project I have a unit test like this:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(BuildingController.class)
class BuildingControllerTest {

    @Value("classpath:building/CreateBuildingRequest.json")
    Resource createBuildingRequest;
...
}
```

I load a test input file using @value annotation, and running `mvn clean verify` run the test case successfully on my IDE.

But when I run the test case in azure pipeline I get fileNotFoundException, saying file does not exist[image]

Here is my azure-pipelines.yaml

```xml
trigger:
  - main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - task: Maven@3
    displayName: 'Package Maven'
    inputs:
      mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
      goals: 'verify'
```

Observation: replacing @value with

```java
Resource createBuildingRequest = new ClassPathResource("Building/CreateBuildingRequest.json");
```

also produce the same problem
BUT, if load like this:

```java
    public static InputStream loadFileAsStream(String path){
        return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
    }
```

Work on both IDE and azure pipeline,

### Why?

Answer (score 1):

I just change my test file folder name from "Building" to building and it works

[image]

However, when I had the folder as "Building", and I changed @value to @Value("classpath:Building/CreateBuildingRequest.json") it didn't work.

Leaving this post up to document this problem.